# Using Card.io on mobile sites (responsive)

Tags: mobile, web

I love the idea of card.io and would love to integrate it for my company. My only question is regarding the application of Card.io. Are we able to implement this for use with mobile site or is it exclusively for apps?

We are building out a new fully responsive site, launching out next week and I'd love to use this service to make it easier on my almost 50% of mobile shoppers to purchase product. If this product is not capable of fulfilling these needs would much appreciate a recommendation of a similar service which could help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Dave from card.io here.

It is not possible to use card.io within a mobile browser. The SDK can be integrated only into a mobile app.